# Multi-monitor 3D Application

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d, ogre3d

I've been challenged with a C++ 3D application project that will use 3 displays, each one rendering from a different camera.

Recently I learned about Ogre3D but it's not clear if it supports output of different cameras to different displays/GPUs.

Does anyone have any experience with a similar Setup and Ogre or another engine?

Answer (score 3):

At least on most systems (e.g., Windows, MacOS) the windowing system creates a virtual desktop, with different monitors mapped to different parts of the desktop. If you want to, you can (for example) create one big window that will cover all three displays. If you set that window up to use OpenGL, almost anything that uses OpenGL (almost certainly including Ogre3D) will work just fine, though in some cases producing that much output resolution can tax the graphics card to the point that it's a bit slower than usual.

If you want to deal with a separate window on each display, things might be a bit more complex. OpenGL itself doesn't (even attempt to) define how to handle display in multiple windows -- that's up to a platform-specific set of functions. On Windows, for example, you have a rendering context for each window, and have to use `WGLMakeCurrent` to pick which rendering context you draw to at any given time.

If memory serves, the Windows port of Ogre3D supports multiple rendering contexts, so this shouldn't be a problem either. I'd expect it can work with multiple windows on other systems as well, but I haven't used it on any other systems, so I can't say with any certainty.

My immediate guess, however, is that the triple monitor support will be almost inconsequential in your overall development effort. Of course, it *does* mean that you (can tell your boss) need a triple monitor setup for development and testing, which certainly isn't a bad thing! :-)

Edit: OpenGL itself doesn't specify anything about full-screen windows vs. normal windows. If memory serves, at least on Windows to get a full screen application, you use `ChangeDisplaySettings` with `CDS_FULLSCREEEN`. After that, it treats essentially the entire virtual desktop as a single window. I don't recall having done that with multiple monitors though, so I can't say much with any great certainty.

Comment: Hello Jerry, thak you for your answer. It's not necessarily a separate window for each display, because it needs to be full screen on each display (I'm not sure if this kind of output depends on a window or bypasses the windowing system). What is your opinion?

Comment: same is true for LINUX: if you're using multiple monitors, you're typically using Xinerama, which creates one huge virtual screen.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to be said about multihead support in the case of OGRE3D. In my experience, a working solution is to use the source version of Ogre 1.6.1 and apply [this patch](http://ogre.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ogre?view=rev&revision=8308).
Using this patch, users have managed to render an Ogre application on a [6 monitors configuration](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=48032).

Personnaly, I've successfully applied this patch, and used it with the [StereoManager plugin](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=32284) to hook up Ogre applications with a 3D projector. I only used the Direct3D9 backend. The StereoManager plugin comes with a modified demo (`Fresnel_Demo`), which can help you to set up your first multihead application.

I should also add that the multihead patch is now part of the Ogre core, as of version 1.7. Ogre1.7 was recently released as a RC1,  so this  might be the quickest and easiest way to have it working.